# Removing fields from struct or hiding them in JSON Response

Tags: json, go

I've created an API in Go that, upon being called, performs a query, creates an instance of a struct, and then encodes that struct as JSON before sending back to the caller.  I'd now like to allow the caller to be able to select the specific fields they would like returned by passing in a "fields" GET parameter.

This means depending on the fields value(s), my struct would change.  Is there any way to remove fields from a struct?  Or at least hide them in the JSON response dynamically?  (Note: Sometimes I have empty values so the JSON omitEmpty tag will not work here)  If neither of these are possible, is there a suggestion on a better way to handle this?

A smaller version of the structs I'm using are below:

```
type SearchResult struct {
    Date        string      `json:"date"`
    IdCompany   int         `json:"idCompany"`
    Company     string      `json:"company"`
    IdIndustry  interface{} `json:"idIndustry"`
    Industry    string      `json:"industry"`
    IdContinent interface{} `json:"idContinent"`
    Continent   string      `json:"continent"`
    IdCountry   interface{} `json:"idCountry"`
    Country     string      `json:"country"`
    IdState     interface{} `json:"idState"`
    State       string      `json:"state"`
    IdCity      interface{} `json:"idCity"`
    City        string      `json:"city"`
} //SearchResult

type SearchResults struct {
    NumberResults int            `json:"numberResults"`
    Results       []SearchResult `json:"results"`
} //type SearchResults
```

I then encode and output the response like so:

```
err := json.NewEncoder(c.ResponseWriter).Encode(&msg)
```

Comment: @Jacob, as per PuerkitoBio's updated answer, I think you mis-read the question. The (currently) accepted might not be the "correct answer" to **your** question, but is to the one asked here! The (currently) highest voted answer may answer *your* question but is *completely inapplicable* to this one!

Answer (score 474, accepted):

The question is asking for fields to be **dynamically** selected based on the caller-provided list of fields. This isn't possible to be done with the statically-defined json struct tag.

If what you want is to **always** skip a field to json-encode, then of course use `json:"-"` to ignore the field. (Note also that this is **not** required if your field is unexported; those fields are always ignored by the json encoder.) This isn't what the question asks.

To quote the comment on the `json:"-"` answer:

> This [the `json:"-"` answer] is the answer most people ending up here from searching would want, but it's not the answer to the question.

I'd use a `map[string]interface{}` instead of a struct in this case. You can easily remove fields by calling the `delete` built-in on the map for the fields to remove.

That is, if you can't query only for the requested fields in the first place.

Comment: you most likely don't want to throw away your type definition entirely.  That's going to be bothersome down the line, like when you want to write other methods on this type that access those fields.  Using an intermediate `map[string]interface{}` does make sense, but it does not require that you throw away your type definition.

Comment: The other answer is the actual answer to this question.

Comment: A possible drawback of delete is that you sometimes might want to support multiple json views of your struct (map). For example json view for the client without a sensitive field, and json view for the database WITH the sensitive field. Fortunately it is still possible to use the struct -- just have a look at my answer.

Comment: This works for me as I only needed a specific `Id` but, do not want to return the entire json struct. Thanks for this!

Comment: A tag is just part of the reflection and that's how it's used to encode/decode JSON data. Could you change the reflection dynamically and in this way do what the OP wanted?

Comment: Where is `"-"` standard come from? Is it from `go` language, or some framework, like `gin`?

Comment: It is possible via `json:"xxx,omitempty"`, by setting the field to nill before return, as another answer said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20413334 ,

Answer (score 242):

use `json:"-"`

```
// Field is ignored by this package.
Field int `json:"-"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "myName".
Field int `json:"myName"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "myName" and
// the field is omitted from the object if its value is empty,
// as defined above.
Field int `json:"myName,omitempty"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "Field" (the default), but
// the field is skipped if empty.
// Note the leading comma.
Field int `json:",omitempty"`
```

doc : http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: I'd disagree @Jacob because the OP said they wanted to dynamically control the output fields based on query string entries to the API.  For example, if the caller to the API only asks for Industry and Country, you would then need to remove the rest.  This is why the "ticked" answer is marked as an answer to this question.  This highly-voted answer is for marking fields explicitly never-available-to-any-builtin-json-marshaler - EVER.  if you want it dynamically, the ticked answer is the answer.

Comment: This is the answer most people ending up here from searching would want, but it's not the answer to the question.

Comment: As stated already the OP was asking for a method to dynamically form a DTO.

Answer (score 85):

Another way to do this is to have a struct of **pointers** with the `,omitempty` tag. If the pointers are **nil**, the fields won't be Marshalled.

This method will not require additional reflection or inefficient use of maps.

Same example as jorelli using this method: http://play.golang.org/p/JJNa0m2_nw

Comment: +1 Completely agree.  I use this rule/trick all the time with the built-in marshalers (and even built a CSV reader/writer based off of this rule as well! - I may open-source that soon as yet another csv go package).  The OP could then simply not set the *Country value to nil, and it would be omitted.  And awesome that you supplied a nice;y typed play.golang as well.

Comment: Of course that method requires reflection, the stdlib's json-to-struct marshaling always uses reflection (actually it always uses reflection period, map or struct or whatever).

Comment: Yes, but it does not require _additional_ reflection using interfaces, which some other answers recommend.

Comment: this is the best way to dynamically display fields

Comment: This is the best answer imo.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `reflect` package to select the fields that you want by reflecting on the field tags and selecting the `json` tag values.  Define a method on your SearchResults type that selects the fields you want and returns them as a `map[string]interface{}`, and then marshal *that* instead of the SearchResults struct itself.  Here's an example of how you might define that method:

```
func fieldSet(fields ...string) map[string]bool {
    set := make(map[string]bool, len(fields))
    for _, s := range fields {
        set[s] = true
    }
    return set
}

func (s *SearchResult) SelectFields(fields ...string) map[string]interface{} {
    fs := fieldSet(fields...)
    rt, rv := reflect.TypeOf(*s), reflect.ValueOf(*s)
    out := make(map[string]interface{}, rt.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        field := rt.Field(i)
        jsonKey := field.Tag.Get("json")
        if fs[jsonKey] {
            out[jsonKey] = rv.Field(i).Interface()
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

and here's a runnable solution that shows how you would call this method and marshal your selection:  http://play.golang.org/p/1K9xjQRnO8

Comment: come to think of it, you could reasonably generalize the selectfields pattern to any type and any tag key; there's nothing about this that is specific to the SearchResult definition or the json key.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from reflection but this saves type information pretty nicely... It's nice to have code that documents what your structures look like better than a bunch of if/else tags in a validate() method (if you even have one)

Answer (score 9):

I just published [sheriff](https://github.com/liip/sheriff), which transforms structs to a map based on tags annotated on the struct fields. You can then marshal (JSON or others) the generated map. It probably doesn't allow you to only serialize the set of fields the caller requested, but I imagine using a set of groups would allow you to cover most cases. Using groups instead of the fields directly would most likely also increase cache-ability.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-version"
    "github.com/liip/sheriff"
)

type User struct {
    Username string   `json:"username" groups:"api"`
    Email    string   `json:"email" groups:"personal"`
    Name     string   `json:"name" groups:"api"`
    Roles    []string `json:"roles" groups:"api" since:"2"`
}

func main() {
    user := User{
        Username: "alice",
        Email:    "alice@example.org",
        Name:     "Alice",
        Roles:    []string{"user", "admin"},
    }

    v2, err := version.NewVersion("2.0.0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    o := &sheriff.Options{
        Groups:     []string{"api"},
        ApiVersion: v2,
    }

    data, err := sheriff.Marshal(o, user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    output, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", output)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Take three ingredients:

1. The `reflect` package to loop over all the fields of a struct.
2. An `if` statement to pick up the fields you want to `Marshal`, and
3. The `encoding/json` package to `Marshal` the fields of your liking.

Preparation:

1. Blend them in a good proportion. Use `reflect.TypeOf(your_struct).Field(i).Name()` to get a name of the `i`th field of `your_struct`.
2. Use `reflect.ValueOf(your_struct).Field(i)` to get a type `Value` representation of an `i`th field of `your_struct`.
3. Use `fieldValue.Interface()` to retrieve the actual value (upcasted to type interface{}) of the `fieldValue` of type `Value` (note the bracket use - the Interface() *method* produces `interface{}`

If you luckily manage not to burn any transistors or circuit-breakers in the process you should get something like this:

```
func MarshalOnlyFields(structa interface{},
    includeFields map[string]bool) (jsona []byte, status error) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(structa)
    typa := reflect.TypeOf(structa)
    size := value.NumField()
    jsona = append(jsona, '{')
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        structValue := value.Field(i)
        var fieldName string = typa.Field(i).Name
        if marshalledField, marshalStatus := json.Marshal((structValue).Interface()); marshalStatus != nil {
            return []byte{}, marshalStatus
        } else {
            if includeFields[fieldName] {
                jsona = append(jsona, '"')
                jsona = append(jsona, []byte(fieldName)...)
                jsona = append(jsona, '"')
                jsona = append(jsona, ':')
                jsona = append(jsona, (marshalledField)...)
                if i+1 != len(includeFields) {
                    jsona = append(jsona, ',')
                }
            }
        }
    }
    jsona = append(jsona, '}')
    return
}
```

Serving:

serve with an arbitrary struct and a `map[string]bool` of fields you want to include, for example

```
type magic struct {
    Magic1 int
    Magic2 string
    Magic3 [2]int
}

func main() {
    var magic = magic{0, "tusia", [2]int{0, 1}}
    if json, status := MarshalOnlyFields(magic, map[string]bool{"Magic1": true}); status != nil {
        println("error")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(json))
    }

}
```

Bon Appetit!

Comment: Warning! If your includeFields contain field names, which do not match the actual fields, you're going to get an invalid json. You have been warned.

Answer (score 7):

I created this function to convert struct to JSON string by ignoring some fields. Hope it will help.

```
func GetJSONString(obj interface{}, ignoreFields ...string) (string, error) {
    toJson, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if len(ignoreFields) == 0 {
        return string(toJson), nil
    }

    toMap := map[string]interface{}{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(toJson)), &toMap)

    for _, field := range ignoreFields {
        delete(toMap, field)
    }

    toJson, err = json.Marshal(toMap)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(toJson), nil
}
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/nmq7MFF47Gp

Comment: Kudos for not over-engineering the living jeebers out of the issue. You probably don't need to do the marshal/map/marshal business, but nice solution!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I defined my structure.

```
type User struct {
    Username string  `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    Email    string  `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Password *string `json:"password,omitempty" bson:"password"`
    FullName string  `json:"fullname" bson:"fullname"`
}
```

And inside my function set `user.Password = nil` for not to be Marshalled.

Answer (score 4):

You can use tagging attribute "omitifempty" or make optional fields pointers and leave those you want skipped uninitialized.

Comment: This is the most correct answer to the OPs question and use case.

Comment: @user1943442, not it is not; the OP *explicitly* mentions why "omitempty" is inapplicable.

Answer (score 2):

The question is now a bit old, but I came across the same issue a little while ago, and as I found no easy way to do this, I built a library fulfilling this purpose.
It allows to easily generate a `map[string]interface{}` from a static struct.

https://github.com/tuvistavie/structomap

Comment: You can now easily do it using a code snippet from my recipe.

Comment: The snippet is a subset of the library, but a major issue here about returning a `[]byte` is that it is not very reusable: no easy way to add a field afterwards, for example. So I would suggest to create a `map[string]interface{}` and let the JSON serialization part to the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have the same problem but similar. Below code solves your problem too, of course if you don't mind performance issue. Before implement that kind of solution to your system I recommend you to redesign your structure if you can. Sending variable structure response is over-engineering. I believe a response structure represents a contract between a request and resource and it should't be depend requests.(you can make un-wanted fields null, I do). In some cases we have to implement this design, if you believe you are in that cases here is the [play link](https://play.golang.org/p/_qrB8o9laZW) and code I use.

```
type User2 struct {
    ID       int    `groups:"id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Username string `groups:"username" json:"username,omitempty"`
    Nickname string `groups:"nickname" json:"nickname,omitempty"`
}

type User struct {
    ID       int    `groups:"private,public" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Username string `groups:"private" json:"username,omitempty"`
    Nickname string `groups:"public" json:"nickname,omitempty"`
}

var (
    tagName = "groups"
)

//OmitFields sets fields nil by checking their tag group value and access control tags(acTags)
func OmitFields(obj interface{}, acTags []string) {
    //nilV := reflect.Value{}
    sv := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    st := sv.Type()
    if sv.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < st.NumField(); i++ {
            fieldVal := sv.Field(i)
            if fieldVal.CanSet() {
                tagStr := st.Field(i).Tag.Get(tagName)
                if len(tagStr) == 0 {
                    continue
                }
                tagList := strings.Split(strings.Replace(tagStr, " ", "", -1), ",")
                //fmt.Println(tagList)
                // ContainsCommonItem checks whether there is at least one common item in arrays
                if !ContainsCommonItem(tagList, acTags) {
                    fieldVal.Set(reflect.Zero(fieldVal.Type()))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//ContainsCommonItem checks if arrays have at least one equal item
func ContainsCommonItem(arr1 []string, arr2 []string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(arr1); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(arr2); j++ {
            if arr1[i] == arr2[j] {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
func main() {
    u := User{ID: 1, Username: "very secret", Nickname: "hinzir"}
    //assume authenticated user doesn't has permission to access private fields
    OmitFields(&u, []string{"public"}) 
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(&u)
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))


    u2 := User2{ID: 1, Username: "very secret", Nickname: "hinzir"}
    //you want to filter fields by field names
    OmitFields(&u2, []string{"id", "nickname"}) 
    bytes, _ = json.Marshal(&u2)
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))

}
```

Comment: reflect is slow

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem, at first I just wanted to specialize the responses in my http handler. My first approach was creating a package that copies the information of a struct to another struct and then marshal that second struct. I did that package using reflection, so, never liked that approach and also I wasn't dynamically.

So I decided to modify the encoding/json package to do this. The functions `Marshal`, `MarshalIndent` and `(Encoder) Encode` additionally receives a

`type F map[string]F`

I wanted to simulate a JSON of the fields that are needed to marshal, so it only marshals the fields that are in the map.

[https://github.com/jtorz/jsont](https://github.com/JuanTorr/jsont)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/jtorz/jsont/v2"
)

type SearchResult struct {
    Date        string      `json:"date"`
    IdCompany   int         `json:"idCompany"`
    Company     string      `json:"company"`
    IdIndustry  interface{} `json:"idIndustry"`
    Industry    string      `json:"industry"`
    IdContinent interface{} `json:"idContinent"`
    Continent   string      `json:"continent"`
    IdCountry   interface{} `json:"idCountry"`
    Country     string      `json:"country"`
    IdState     interface{} `json:"idState"`
    State       string      `json:"state"`
    IdCity      interface{} `json:"idCity"`
    City        string      `json:"city"`
} //SearchResult

type SearchResults struct {
    NumberResults int            `json:"numberResults"`
    Results       []SearchResult `json:"results"`
} //type SearchResults
func main() {
    msg := SearchResults{
        NumberResults: 2,
        Results: []SearchResult{
            {
                Date:        "12-12-12",
                IdCompany:   1,
                Company:     "alfa",
                IdIndustry:  1,
                Industry:    "IT",
                IdContinent: 1,
                Continent:   "america",
                IdCountry:   1,
                Country:     "México",
                IdState:     1,
                State:       "CDMX",
                IdCity:      1,
                City:        "Atz",
            },
            {
                Date:        "12-12-12",
                IdCompany:   2,
                Company:     "beta",
                IdIndustry:  1,
                Industry:    "IT",
                IdContinent: 1,
                Continent:   "america",
                IdCountry:   2,
                Country:     "USA",
                IdState:     2,
                State:       "TX",
                IdCity:      2,
                City:        "XYZ",
            },
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(msg)
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        //{"numberResults":2,"results":[{"date":"12-12-12","idCompany":1,"idIndustry":1,"country":"México"},{"date":"12-12-12","idCompany":2,"idIndustry":1,"country":"USA"}]}
        err := jsont.NewEncoder(w).Encode(msg, jsont.F{
            "numberResults": nil,
            "results": jsont.F{
                "date":       nil,
                "idCompany":  nil,
                "idIndustry": nil,
                "country":    nil,
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":3009", nil)
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but this looks great. It would be even better if Marshaler interface is also supported as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers with `omitempty`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Values struct {
    Num int    `json:"num,omitempty"`
    Str string `json:"str,omitempty"`
}

type Pointers struct {
    Num *int    `json:"num,omitempty"`
    Str *string `json:"str,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var zero int
    var empty string

    vals := Values{
        Num: zero,
        Str: empty,
    }
    data, _ := json.Marshal(vals)
    fmt.Println(string(data)) // prints {}, which is not what we want

    // but if we use pointers:

    pts := Pointers{
        Num: &zero,
        Str: &empty,
    }
    data, _ = json.Marshal(pts)
    fmt.Println(string(data)) // prints {"num":0,"str":""}

    // and if we want to omit them from JSON:

    pts = Pointers{
        Num: nil,
        Str: nil,
    }
    data, _ = json.Marshal(pts)
    fmt.Println(string(data)) // prints {}

}
```

`omitempty` omits zero values of the fields, but pointer to something is not a zero value of pointer, even if variable pointed has zero value.

So to include zero value into JSON, make (non-nil) pointer to zero value, but to omit value from JSON set the pointer itself to nil (or just don't initialize it)

Answer (score 0):

## Update/remove struct fields from serialization based on another field in that struct dynamically

### AKA: Don't serialize the `Content` field if the `Hidden` field is true. Or, Set `Content` to "nothing found!" if the `Hidden` field is true.

##### Example:

For this struct (where `CustomStruct` is any custom struct you have):

```golang
type Post struct {
    Hidden bool `json:"hidden"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    Value CustomStruct `json:"value"`
}
```

You can choose to dynamically return or not the value of any field based on the bool value of `Hidden`.

First, create an alias for your struct:

```golang
type Alias Post
```

Then make a wrapper for the alias:

```golang
type AuxPost struct {
    *Alias
}
```

Then override the `MarshalJSON` method (importing package `"encoding/json"`):

```golang
func (p Post) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias Post
    if p.Hidden {
        hiddenPost := struct {
            Alias
            Content string `json:"content"`
            Value   bool   `json:"value,omitempty"`
        }{
            Alias:   (Alias)(p),
            Content: "[this post was removed]",
            Value:   false,
        }
        return json.Marshal(hiddenPost)

    }
    regularPost := struct {
        Alias
    }{
        Alias: (Alias)(p),
    }
    return json.Marshal(regularPost)
}
```

If your post's `Hidden` field is true, then it will serialize normally. If not, the `Content` field will be set to `"[this post was removed]"` and the `Value` field will be completely omitted (because in this particular case I set `omitempty`).

**... the case where `Hidden` is false serializes as:**

```json
{
  "hidden": true,
  "content": "hello world",
  "value": {
    "note": "your custom struct can have anything"
  }
}
```

**... and the case where `Hidden` is true serializes as:**

```json
{
  "hidden": true,
  "content": "[this post was removed]"
}
```

Removing a non-struct field is trivial, but the way the struct getting removed works is by tricking it into thinking its a boolean, and then setting that bool to false, and omitting zero values from serializations (bool's zero-value = false).

EDIT: If we wanted the `Value` struct to just be serialized as `null` instead, we got remove the `omitempty` tag and instead set its type (previously `bool`) to `*interface{}` and then below as `nil` (previously `false`).

Answer (score -1):

To extend [chhaileng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7496198/chhaileng) answer, here is the version that remove all occurrences of a field with recursion

```
// GetJSONWithOutFields - Description: return a string representation of an interface with specified fields removed
func GetJSONWithOutFields(obj interface{}, ignoreFields ...string) (string, error) {
    toJson, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if len(ignoreFields) == 0 {
        return string(toJson), nil
    }

    toMap := map[string]interface{}{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(toJson, &toMap)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    for _, field := range ignoreFields {
        DeleteField(toMap, field)
    }

    toJson, err = json.Marshal(toMap)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(toJson), nil
}

// DeleteField - Description: recursively delete field
func DeleteField(toMap map[string]interface{}, field string) {
    delete(toMap, field)
    for _, v := range toMap {
        if m, isMap := v.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
            DeleteField(m, field)
        }
    }
}
```