# Is it possible to delete a field of a struct value at runtime?

Tags: go, struct

I have the following struct:

```
type Record struct {
  Id     string   `json:"id"`
  ApiKey string   `json:"apiKey"`
  Body   []string `json:"body"`
  Type   string   `json:"type"`
}
```

Which is a Blueprint of a dynamoDB table. And I need somehow, delete the ApiKey, after using to check if the user has access to the giving record. Explaining:

I have and endpoint in my API where the user can send a `id` to get a item, but he needs to have access to the ID and the ApiKey (I'm using Id (uuid) + ApiKey) to create unique items.

How I'm doing:

```
 func getExtraction(id string, apiKey string) (Record, error) {
    svc := dynamodb.New(cfg)

    req := svc.GetItemRequest(&dynamodb.GetItemInput{
      TableName: aws.String(awsEnv.Dynamo_Table),
      Key: map[string]dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "id": {
          S: aws.String(id),
        },
      },
    })

    result, err := req.Send()
    if err != nil {
      return Record{}, err
    }

    record := Record{}
    err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &record)
    if err != nil {
      return Record{}, err
    }

    if record.ApiKey != apiKey {
      return Record{}, fmt.Errorf("item %d not found", id)
    }
    // Delete ApiKey from record
    return record, nil
  }
```

After checking if the ApiKey is equal to the provided `apiKey`, I want to delete the `ApiKey` from `record`, but unfortunately that's not possible using `delete`.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot modify a struct's type definition at runtime. A value of a struct type will always have all fields of the struct type definition.

Comment: Do you just want to blank it out with an empty string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing fields from struct or hiding them in JSON Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306358/removing-fields-from-struct-or-hiding-them-in-json-response)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no way to actually edit a golang type (such as a struct) at runtime. Unfortunately you haven't really explained what you are hoping to achieve by "deleting" the APIKey field.

General approaches would be:

1. set the APIKey field to an empty string after inspection, if you dont want to display this field when empty set the json struct tag to omitempty (e.g `json:"apiKey,omitempty"`)
2. set the APIKey field to never Marshal into JSON ( e.g ApiKey string   `json:"-"`) and you will still be able to inspect it just wont display in JSON, you could take this further by adding a custom marshal / unmarshal function to handle this in one direction or in a context dependent way
3. copy the data to a new struct, e.g type RecordNoAPI struct without the APIKey field and return that after you have inspected the original Record

Answer (score 2):

1. Created RecordShort structure without "ApiKey"
2. Marshalin Record
3. Unmarsaling Record to ShortRecord

```golang
type RecordShot struct {
  Id     string   `json:"id"`
  Body   []string `json:"body"`
  Type   string   `json:"type"`
}
    
record,_:=json.Marshal(Record)
json.Unmarshal([]byte(record), &RecordShot)
```